# Sequence of content changed while using multiple columns css3 in safari

Tags: html, css

Kindly find my code [here](https://codepen.io/kamalakkanni/pen/aXLYdx?editors=1100) I got content sequence like as 1 3 2 4 in safari whereas it is fine in all other browsers.I used multiple column css3.

For example, I am having content as

```
சென்னை, மதுரை என 30-க்கும் மேற்பட்ட இடங்களில் 
நடைபெற்ற
```

Below is my output (after column division) in chrome,firefox,ie,edge

```
            1                      2              3             4
      சென்னை, மதுரை | என 30-க்கும் |மேற்பட்ட| இடங்களில்
```

In ipad safari and mac safari

```
            1                      3            2             4
       சென்னை, மதுரை |இடங்களில்| என 30-க்கும்| மேற்பட்ட
```

Can anyone please help me to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: [here][1] ??? where?

Comment: You can use media queries ... https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Any specific OS?

Comment: Ipad os10.3.3.             MacOS Sierra v10.12.6